# Apache Spark using data stored in Parquet file: is a second sorting (as if a secondary index was existing) possible?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I've stored the enterprises and establishments list of France in a parquet file, and their keys are the identifiers (*siren*, *siret*) of existing companies, that allow to search them quickly from these public and known ids.
The underlying parquet file storing this data is about 1 GB size.

But in one use case on two, someone is asking:

> What are all the enterprises/establishments in a city ?

instead of searching them by their ids.

I could have sorted my previous parquet file by {*city_code*, *siren*, *siret*} instead. But then, the research of enterprises/establishments by their ids only would be slowered...

I cannot afford to reorder the data at search time, so I must manage this when I prepare and store the data.

Currently, I see for only solution :

1. Creating a `enterprises_establishments_by_ids` parquet file,
2. Creating a `enterprises_establishments_by_cities_codes_and_ids` parquet file,
3. Finding a way to detect what the user is asking, and then read the initial data from the most convenient store: **1** or **2**.

But it's clumsy. And it doubles the data storage to 2 GB.
Does a better way exist to handle this problem ?

Comment: You need not duplicate the entire dataset to create `enterprises_establishments_by_cities_codes_and_ids`. By storing only the city codes and ids in this dataset the size would be reduced. When a user searches based on city , you could query this dataset to determine the ids which you could then use to query the establishments from the originally indexed `enterprises_establishments_by_ids`

Answer (score 0):

You could partition you dataframe by `city_code` when storing the parquet file, like that you could only load the partition that correspond to the city code you want.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy

you could try something like this when storing your 1GB dataframe

`enterprises_establishments.write.partitionBy('city_code').parquet('your_path/my_file.parquet'))`

when a user is requesting, What are all the enterprises/establishments in a city ?

`enterprises_establishments_in_city = spark.read.parquet('your_path/my_file.parquet/city_code=wanted_city_code')`

But I think that doing a filter on your dataframe is not going to be that slow

`enterprises_establishments_in_city = enterprises_establishments.filter(enterprises_establishments.city_code == wanted_city_code)`